# Can cannabidiol help on Autism Spectrum Disorder?

Tags: autism, alternative-medicine, cannabidiol, cytokines

Spanish doctor Mariano Garcia de Palau, [aseverates in a cannabic website](https://www.fundacion-canna.es/cannabinoides-y-trastorno-de-espectro-autista-tea), childs with autism experiment improvements derived from the consume of non psychoactive compund of Cannabis, Cannabidiol (CBD).

> Many of these children seem unhappy and have pain or are suffering
>   continuously, and at the beginning of treatment seems to change this
>   circumstance or at least improve, some smile and others laugh!
>
> These small changes, for many insignificant ones, represent for the
>   parents a great step and some reasonable expectations, which did not
>   exist before.

CBD has been proved to regulate cytokines in rats, reducing proinflamatory cytokines and augmenting antiinflamatory ones (Napimoga et al, 2009).

As far as I know, it has been observed people with ASD have elevated cytokines in general (Ashwood et al, 2011).

I know there are not enoght studies of action of CBD, but it looks to act as an immunosupresant, while ASD [is sugested to be related with autoimmunity](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20019/is-autism-an-autoimmune-disease).

My question is:

Can CBD be helpfull for autism because of actions on antibodies?

In other terms:

Can CBD interact negatively with other antibodies than cytokines, becoming harmfull (or helpfull) for an ASD?

---

[-**Paul Ashwood, Paula Krakowiak, Irva Hertz-Picciotto, Robin Hansen Isaac, Pessah Judy Van de Water (2011)**: *"Elevated plasma cytokines in autism spectrum disorders provide evidence of immune dysfunction and are associated with impaired behavioral outcome."*, **Brain, Behavior, and Immunity**, Volume 25, Issue 1, Pages 40-45.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0889159110004289)

[-**Marcelo H. Napimoga, Bruno B. Benatti, Flavia O. Lima, Polyanna M. Alvesa, Allin C. Campos, Diego R. Pena-dos-Santos, Fernando P. Severino, Fernando Q. Cunha, Francisco S. Guimarães (2009)**: *"Cannabidiol decreases bone resorption by inhibiting RANK/RANKL expression and pro-inflammatory cytokines during experimental periodontitis in rats"*, **International Immunopharmacology**, Volume 9, Issue 2, Pages 216-222](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1567576908003469)

Comment: The suggestion of ASD being an autoimmune disease is quite controversial. Alternatively, there are a lot of hints that autism has to do with altered neural pathways due to genetic mutations, such as SHANK3, IP3, CHRNA7 and others. The hypothesis or researches following this line of argument is that somehow such mutations result in lowered immune activity. Therefore, treating the immune system by whatever means will alleviate co-morbidity of autism, but of course it has no effect on neither the pathways nor the genes themselves. TL;DR: Highly unlikely.

Comment: @Narusan Yes, the doctor don't says it cures autism, he says it alleviate comorbid issues as you mention. I also think there is a genetic compound, and of course anything can change the genome of someone. But if those gens have an action on immune system, maybe the reason why those childs smile for fist time is because CBD interacts with that immunologic system altered by gens. There my question.

Comment: I am particullary interested in interaction between CBD and chemokynes as possibly harmfull for and immune type or immune related type of autism.